# Convert Property from Int to String and show it in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, knockout.js

I want to convert my Int values to string with a json that i created. 
My variable ResultType is in INT and i want to show the converted value of it.
ResultType hold the values int, so "1", "2" etc from my db.

Here is my main.js code

```
function InvestigatorInfo() {
  var self = this;
  self.ResultType = ko.observable();
}
InvestigatorInfo.prototype.fromJS = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.ResultType(data.ResultType || "");
}
```

And my View:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:Infos">
<b>ResultType: </b><span data-bind="text: resultName[ResultType]"></span>
```

this is my code for converting:

```
resultName = {"0":"INVALID_VALUE","1":"NONE","2":"BOOLEAN"}
```

Do i need to check it for int first in my prototype function?
any help would be apreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ko.computed`.

In the sample below I have put the type/name map (`resultTypeNames`) as a static constructor property.

```js
function InvestigatorInfo() {
  var self = this;
  self.ResultType = ko.observable();
  self.ResultName = ko.computed(function () {
    return InvestigatorInfo.resultTypeNames[self.ResultType()] || "UNKNOWN";
  });
}
InvestigatorInfo.prototype.fromJS = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.ResultType(data.ResultType || "");
  return self;
}
InvestigatorInfo.resultTypeNames = {
  "0":"INVALID_VALUE",
  "1":"NONE",
  "2":"BOOLEAN"
}


var response = [
  { ResultType: "0" },
  { ResultType: "2" },
  { ResultType: "1" },
  { ResultType: "4" }
];

ko.applyBindings({
  Infos: ko.utils.arrayMap(response, function (data) {
    return new InvestigatorInfo().fromJS(data);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach:Infos">
  <li>
    <b>ResultType:</b>
    <span data-bind="text: ResultName"></span> (<span data-bind="text: ResultType"></span>)
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Muli Since you implement your own `.fromJS()` method, look into either the [official mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) or http://coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/.